# Firebase Push Notifications based on app state

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on push notification handling with Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Everything I implemented is working fine, I'm receiving my push notifications as I want (regarding either my app is in foreground, background or killed) 
But my question is:

(gonna present my problem in steps for easier reading)

1. My application is working and its in the foreground.
2. I receive a push notification but i don't open it immediately
3. I kill the app via task manager
4. I try to open the app with the notification but my app breaks and doesn't open.
   (I know it's because of the Intent object that I made before but I didn't find any documentation regarding those kind of situations. Is there any way I can manipulate the same notification which is already showing in the tray so that its intent changes?)

My apps skeleton is made of several activities and many fragments. It begins with the launcher activity which calls my main activity if every parameter that it checks is fine.

My push notification should open a notification fragment which it does if the Intent is for the same app state (background, foreground or killed).

Here is my Firebase Class

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    val userPreferences = UserPreferences()

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {
            val messageTitle: String = remoteMessage.data["title"] ?: "Hotel"
            val message: String = remoteMessage.data["message"] ?: "You have new notification"
            val groupId: String = remoteMessage.data["group_id"]?: "0"
            val id: String = remoteMessage.data["id"]?: "0"

            if(!userPreferences.visibleFragment.isNullOrEmpty() && groupId=="3")//IF NOT NULL OR EMPTY MUST BE CHATFRAGMENT
            {
                //no message since its chat notification and the chatfragment is visible
            }
            else
            {
                if(groupId=="4")
                {
                    MainActivity.isNotificationIconVisible.postValue(true)
                    userPreferences.isNotificationIconVisible=true
                }
                sendNotification(messageTitle, message, groupId, id)
            }
        }
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        }



        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START on_new_token]
    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {


    }
    // [END on_new_token]



    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private fun handleNow() {

    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {

    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private fun sendNotification(messageTitle: String, messageBody: String, groupId : String, id : String) {

        val intent =
                if (userPreferences.isAppDestroyed) {
                    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                } else {
                    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        .putExtra("id", id)
                        .putExtra("groupid", groupId)
                        .putExtra("appDestroyed", userPreferences.isAppDestroyed)
                }
            val pendingIntent =
                if(userPreferences.isAppDestroyed)
                {
                    TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
                        addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                        editIntentAt(0).putExtra("id", id).putExtra("groupid", groupId).putExtra("appDestroyed", userPreferences.isAppDestroyed)
                        getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                }

        val mode = applicationContext?.resources?.configuration?.uiMode?.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
        val channelId = "1"
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            when (mode) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon_from_asset)
                    notificationBuilder.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon_from_asset)
                    notificationBuilder.setColor(Color.GRAY)
                }
                else -> {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon_from_asset)
                    notificationBuilder.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }
            }

        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_icons)
        }
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

MainActivity onNewIntent fun
(fragment transaction code is commented, tested something)

```
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent)
            val data = intent?.extras
            val groupId = data?.getString("groupid")
            val id = data?.getString("id")
            if (data != null) {
                if (groupId == "4") {
                    val bundle = bundleOf("pushNotificationId" to id)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.notificationDetailsFragment, bundle)
                    /*val fragment = NotificationDetailsFragment()
                    fragment.arguments=bundle
                    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    ft.replace(R.id.main_nav_fragment, fragment)
                    ft.commit()*/
                }
                else return
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

LauncherActivity

```
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private val vm: LauncherViewModel by viewModel()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectFeature()
        // set observables
        vm.isSplashScreenShown.observe(this, Observer {

            finish()

            when (it) {
                true -> startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("id",intent?.extras?.getString("id"))
                    .putExtra("groupid",intent?.extras?.getString("groupid")))
                false -> startActivity(Intent(this, WelcomeActivity::class.java))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and part of my manifest if needed

```
<activity
            android:name=".presentation.launcher.LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/BaseAppTheme.NoActionBar.SplashScreenTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.welcome.WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/BaseAppTheme.NoActionBar.TransparentTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.error.ErrorActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/BaseAppTheme.NoActionBar.TransparentTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/BaseAppTheme.NoActionBar.TransparentTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:parentActivityName=".presentation.launcher.LauncherActivity"/>
```

I would love to have it done like Whatsapp does (whatsapp opens their chat even if repeat the steps like I did for my app)

Thank You very much, if something more is needed or I need to reformat my question please advise me to do so.